# Как в Google Maps добавить на карту фиксированный слой?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Как добавить фиксированный слой на всю карту, чтобы при перемещении по карте и "зуммировании" слой оставался закрепленным? Слой должен располагаться на карте под маркерами.

Делаю через кастомный слой `google.maps.OverlayView()`, но такой слой не изменяет положение при перемещении по карте, а остается на своем месте.

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы - требуется всего лишь сделать затемнение карты с определенной прозрачностью.

**Update.**

Есть также решение с рисованием на карте прямоугольника, но при изменении масштаба на некоторое время прямоугольник пропадает, а затем отрисовывается заново.

https://jsfiddle.net/maximzasorin/kj8fo9a9/

```
var mapOverlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    fillColor: '#000000',
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180)
    )
});
```

Comment: Так а может вам нужно использовать google.maps.StyledMapType ?

Comment: @AndriiKulyk Возможно, подскажите, как с помощью стилей добиться такого [эффекта](https://hsto.org/files/374/a7e/a78/374a7ea78d3f4b82991a4c3f6207ec51.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

https://jsfiddle.net/anatolysukhanov/o4f8u3d7/

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: 55.75583,
    lng: 37.6177,
  },
  zoom: 8,
  styles: [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    "stylers": [
      { "saturation": -50},
      { "lightness": -20 },
    ]
  }
]});
```

Comment: Спасибо, подошло такое решение.